# Connect Outdated DiamondMax Plus 9 160GB via USB

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, external-hard-drive

I am attempting to get the files off of a very old DiamondMax Plus 9 160GB HDD via USB (I think it dates to around 2004/2005). When I plug it in, there is no 'ring' to indicate Windows is even registering it has been plugged in/received, nor does it show up in Device Manager or Disk Management.

My cable has a separate power cord, so I do not think I need to be concerned about power being the problem. I am using these same cables (the power to SATA and usb to  SATA) to connect to other, not quite as old, hard drives, so the cords themselves are in working condition. My ports seem to work fine. I have a Windows laptop that I am trying to connect them too. Just out of curiosity, I plugged it in to my Linux desktop, but nothing showed up there either.

I have looked for some drivers, but nothing specific seems to come up. The closest I can find is [here](https://www.seagate.com/support/internal-hard-drives/desktop-hard-drives/diamondmax/) and [here](http://semantic.gs/maxtor_diamondmax_plus_9_160gb_driver_v2_download). Neither driver manager seemed to help. Also, when I hold my ear down to the drive, I can hear some mechanical whirring, so the hardware itself seems to be operating as well. If it was malfunctioning, how would I be able to tell?

Any guidance, clarification, information, or otherwise would be helpful. I am fairly new to all of this.

Comment: Does the hard drive make noise when connected? It could be already dead since you tried both in Windows and Linux.

Comment: Can you hear it spinning the disk platters? Put your ear to it.

Comment: Yes, the drive does make a noise. As far as it spinning the disk platters, I am not sure how to differentiate that specific noise from general mechanical whirring. I spoke with a learned co-worker today, I think the disc is either scratched or the reader component is off. I am currently looking for a hardware expert, hopefully I will learn a thing or two in the process.

Comment: I spoke with an electrical engineer and we noticed the disk didn't seem to be spinning (despite the presence of mechanical whirring) since we couldn't feel torque when moving the drive freely. I am still working on this and hoping to have an answer as soon as possible.